# MongoDB text search should be case insensitive (SearchString == searchstring)

Tags: mongodb, search

I use this method in my application:

```
@Query("{$text : { $search : ?0,  $caseSensitive: true }}")
List<Item> findItemBySearchString(final String searchString);
```

and $caseSensitive does not work, either with true nor with false.
My Item has the name **Test** -> If I search for **Test** I find it, with **test** I did not find it.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thats an Document:

```
@Document(collection = "Item")
public class Item {

@Id
private String id;
@TextIndexed
private String number; 
@TextIndexed(weight = 2)
private String name; 
private List<String> names;
private String description;
```

and that is my current search method:

```
 @Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 }}")
List<Item> findItemBySearchString(final String searchString);
```

Comment: Post a sample document from your collection

Comment: what is mongodb version?

Comment: MongoDB Version 3.4.5